# Phase correlation between an excited and ground state in a BEC

Tags: statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate

What happens to the phase of the atom that gets kicked out of the atomic condensate? Is it completely random or does it have some correlation with the condensate phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to formulate the question more precisely and then give my answer.

The ``phase'' $\theta$ of a BEC is introduced as $\langle \psi_N|\hat{a}|\psi_{N+1}\rangle = |\psi|e^{i\theta}$, where $|\psi_N\rangle$ is the ground state being occupied by $N$ bosons. Because the occupation number of the condensed state $|\psi_N\rangle$ is of the order $N$, the phase defined above is shared among a macroscopic number of bosons.

Thermal excited states are occupied by the number of particles of the order 1. Without interactions, their phases are generally independent of each other, and independent of the atoms on the ground state (atoms in the BEC). In this sense, the thermal atoms have``completely random" phases.

In the presence of interactions, if what you mean is the randomness of the thermal atoms, I think that will always be the case: the thermally excited atoms always have phases unrelated to each other, for otherwise the presence of a collective phase would serve to define another BEC for particles sharing that phase.

On the other hand, the term ``correlation'' may mean single particle density matrix $\langle \hat{a}_i^\dagger \hat{a}_j\rangle$, where $i,j$ are general labels for bosons. Then it is possible for bosons in the condensate to affect the thermal atoms, and form certain correlation with the condensed bosons (i.e. the $i,j$ represents thermal and condensed bosons respectively). But in this sense, the phase of the thermal bosons is not chiefly a concern, as the phases of thermal atoms are different from each other anyway.

Hopefully this will least partly answer your questions.